# Error in Jupyter notebook "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Hi below are the mentioned codes which I used for executing if condition in jupyter notebook. However there are error of indented block occur. I'm guessing this is because of space issue. However I not sure how to fix it. Could you please help me out for this?

```
    def remove_common_text(lst):
            if len(lst) > 4:
                for itm in lst:
                    if len(itm)>1:
                        rep = True
                        while rep == True:
                            ctr = 0
                            ctr2 = 0
                            for itm2 in lst:
                                if len(itm2)>0:
                                    if itm[0] == itm2[0]:
                                        ctr = ctr + 1
                                    if itm[-1] == itm2[-1]:
                                        ctr2 = ctr2 + 1
                           if ctr > 4:
                                str = itm[0]
                                for itm2 in lst:
                                    if len(itm2)>0:
                                        if itm2[0] == str and len(itm2)>1:
                                            del itm2[0]
                            if ctr2 > 4:
                                str2 = itm[-1]
                                for itm2 in lst:
                                    if len(itm2)>0:
                                        if itm2[-1] == str2 and len(itm2)>1:
                                            del itm2[-1]
                            if (ctr <= 4 and ctr2 <= 4) or len(itm)<=1: rep = False
    id_unique = documents['ID'].unique()
    print(id_unique)
for id in id_unique:


remove_common_text(documents[documents.ID==id]['split_clean'])
print(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

An indentation error, means that used too few or too many tabs (or spaces) somewhere and now a block of code is positioned to far right or left to be interpreted right.
The ones I found:
 - The whole block in which you define remove_common_text() should be moved one tab to the left (line 1-27)
 - There is one indent to many before the first `if len(lst) > 4:` in line 2 an consequently all following lines in the function definition
 - `if ctr > 4:` (line 15) misses one space to be properly indented

If you fix these you get a code without indentation errors:

```
def remove_common_text(lst):
    if len(lst) > 4:
        for itm in lst:
            if len(itm)>1:
                rep = True
                while rep == True:
                    ctr = 0
                    ctr2 = 0
                    for itm2 in lst:
                        if len(itm2)>0:
                            if itm[0] == itm2[0]:
                                ctr = ctr + 1
                            if itm[-1] == itm2[-1]:
                                ctr2 = ctr2 + 1
                    if ctr > 4:
                        str = itm[0]
                        for itm2 in lst:
                            if len(itm2)>0:
                                if itm2[0] == str and len(itm2)>1:
                                    del itm2[0]
                    if ctr2 > 4:
                        str2 = itm[-1]
                        for itm2 in lst:
                            if len(itm2)>0:
                                if itm2[-1] == str2 and len(itm2)>1:
                                    del itm2[-1]
                    if (ctr <= 4 and ctr2 <= 4) or len(itm)<=1: rep = False
id_unique = documents['ID'].unique()
print(id_unique)
for id in id_unique:
    remove_common_text(documents[documents.ID==id]['split_clean'])
print(id)
```

Comment: Hi I modified my code as per your comment, however I'm still facing same error. Any other idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you maybe provide the full code, so I can see whether the problem lies somewhere else?